# to get a value from an array in node js

Tags: javascript

```
const psp=[
  object1="10",
  object2="20"
]
psps.post(psp)
psps.forEach(psp1=>{
  console.log(psp1.object1)
})
```

While I'm running this code I'm getting `undefined` value on my terminal I like to get an output i.e 10 (object1 value)

Comment: What's `psps` ?

Comment: const psps=[] psps.push(psp) just created one new global array and added psp array vale to psps

Answer (score 3):

`psp` in an array and arrays don't have keys. Objects do:

```
const psp = {     // curly braces for object definition
  object1: "10",  // colon instead of equal sign
  object2: "20"
}
```

---

What actually happens in your code is that `psp` resolves to an array containing two strings `"10"` and `"20"`, because `object1="10"` resolves to the assigned value. However, if you meant this to be an object with `object1` and `object2` to be its keys, you need to use curly braces to define an object and a colon between keys and values, as mentioned above.

If you don't need the keys and indeed intended to use an array, you can do so like this:

```
const psp = [
  "10",
  "20"
]
psps.push(psp)

psps.forEach(psp1 => {
  console.log(psp1)
})
```